# Comma use: Physical therapy hours were derived from the funding codes for rehabilitation, which, for the most part, have pre-defined lengths

Tags: british-english, commas

**Sentence**

> Physical therapy hours were derived from the funding codes for rehabilitation, which, for the most part, have pre-defined lengths.

Is it correct to put commas before and after "which"?

Comment: Is 'codes' defined as 'lengths of time laid down in a certain article (etc)' or 'rules regarding lengths of time ...'? If the second, 'have' is perhaps better rendered 'specify'. The commas are acceptable, though we're heading towards comma clutter with three. I'd suggest << Physical therapy hours were derived from the funding codes for rehabilitation, which (for the most part) have/specify pre-defined lengths. >> If this is thought to add undesirable emphasis, << Physical therapy hours were derived from the funding codes for rehabilitation. These mostly have/specify required lengths. >>

Comment: Are you talking about the number of hours allotted to someone, or the total number allotted to a rehab facility? Because to me, *physical therapy hours* refers to time slots, like open 8:00 to 4:00, not to a time allotment as would be suggested by a funding constraint. The smallest change, and probably not the best, would be to change *lengths* to *allotments*.

Comment: *for the most part* is a parenthetical phrase, so yes, it should be set off with commas even though it looks a bit awkward to have *which* appear with commas fore and aft.